# Joomla freaked out after domain parking

Tags: joomla

I'm going nuts. I wanted to run simple personal website on Joomla 3. Everything worked perfect on localhost and on web server. But then, I have parked my personal domain and things went bad.
Webpage works BUT:

- I cant change global configuration in admin panel
- When try to switch something in k2_module (whatever, dosen't matter) I get errors like

> Warning: require_once(/home/u973326837/public_html/administrator/components/com_k2/controllers/.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u973326837/public_html/administrator/components/com_k2/k2.php on line 131

And that code goes like this:

```
129 $controller = JRequest::getWord('view', 'items');
130 $controller = JString::strtolower($controller);
131 require_once (JPATH_COMPONENT.DS.'controllers'.DS.$controller.'.php');
```

- couldn't log into panel admin because of

> Cannot open file for writing log

that was easy to solve by changing

```
public $log_path = 'logs';
```

and everything seems like it dosen't see the whole new domain. I've changed

> public $live_site =

but it dosen't do anything.

Is there any other place that my old domain could've remained?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to modify the configuration.php file directly? Check the setting for `public $tmp_path` and verify that is set corrrectly, usually it is something like `./tmp` (or you could put the complete path to the tmp folder)